# Proving Blow up of Solution by comparing with ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

We can figure out that for the ODE $u'(t)=f(u(t))$ the solution is global if $\int_{M}^{\infty}\frac{du}{f(u)}=\infty$. $(M>0)$

1. I cannot find out why this condition is sufficient for blow up of above ODE.
2. Use the ODE above to conclude that the solution for $u_t-\Delta u=f(u)$ is global iff $\int_{M}^{\infty}\frac{du}{f(u)}=\infty$. $(M>0)$.

Can anyone suggest me good references where I can find out the theory for blow up of Equations by comparing with ODEs.

Regards

Comment: where does your first sentence come from? why is that true and what is $M$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume $f(u)>0$ for $u\ge M$.

1. The solution with initial condition $u(0)=M$ is given implicitely by
   $$
   \int_M^u\frac{ds}{f(s)}=t.
   $$
   Let $F(u)=\int_M^u\frac{ds}{f(s)}$. $F$ is strictly increasing on $[M,\infty)$ and $\lim_{u\to\infty}F(u)=\infty$. It has an inverse $F^{-1}\colon[0,\infty)\to[M,\infty)$ and
   $$
   u(t)=F^{-1}(t).
   $$
2. Any solution of $u_t-\Delta u=f(u)$ with initial value $u_0$ such that $0\le u_0(x)\le M$ is bounded by the solution of $u'=f(u)$ with $u(0)=M$. The **iff** part is wrong. Blow up may depend both on $f$ and on the size of $u_0$. For instance, $u_t-\Delta u=u^p$ has global solutions for sufficiently small $u_0$ if $p>1+2/n$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, please tell me why solutions of $u_t-\Delta u=f(u)$ are bounded by solutions for $u'=f(u)$. Please suggest some references where theory for comparison with ODEs can be found.

Comment: Maximum principle.

Comment: Let $u$ and $v$ are solutions of PDE and ODE respectively with same initial data. It turns out that $$\frac{d}{dt}(u-v)-\Delta (u-v)=f(u)-f(v)$$. and $(u-v)(0)=0\geq 0$. I cannot figure out what maximum principle I should by given condition on $f$.

Comment: $u$ and $v$ satisfy the same equation. $u_0(x)\le v(0)$. Then, under certain conditions on $f$, $u(x,t)\le v(t)$.

Comment: yes, But is $\int_{M}^{\infty}\frac{du}{f(u)}$ enough to conclude the maximum principle? I try but I think it is not possible. Please tell me some good reference to study maximum/comparision principle for Parabolic PDEs. I suppose the case $f(u)-u^p$ for $p>1$ (f is lipchitz and $f(0)=0$, so $|f(u)|\leq C|u|$ is one case where we can conclude something.